# Remove extra articles

Tags: articles

> Or simply extract the(1) file whose name is the(2) output of the(3) 'where .\%clcacheArtifactName%:*.tar*' command

What of the articles (1-3) should or must be replaced/removed. If there is more than one option of the sentence's look, please write which is (are) more preferable.

Comment: All the articles should stay. They refer to specific instances which indicate the use of "the"

Comment: I could see using *a* for (1) or for (3) if there could be more than one file chosen, or there could be more than one command like that.

Comment: With very few and rare exceptions, all singular countable nouns should be qualified by a determiner.